# Importing image from a folder, and sorting them. Market 1501

Tags: python, database, jupyter-notebook

So I have 5933 images, all 64x28, which contain identities of 300 people. These are from Market 1501. These are contained in a folder named Training.

These are to be used for training my model. The images are labelled as person_camera_someotherinfo_00

Examples:
0001_c1s1_001051_00.jpg
0001_c2s1_002301_00.jpg
0001_c5s3_072862_00.jpg

These are for 1 person.

0002_c1s1_000841_00.jpg
0002_c2s1_064446_00.jpg
0002_c3s1_000501_00.jpg

I want to extract these images in jupyter notebook so that I can use them for training. I think I will use tensorflows for this. What approach can I use? How to get arrays from this data which then I can work upon?
Please guide. I am kind of a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

With the **bounding_box_train** in the same directory of the jupyter file, you can use:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2


def create_dataset(img_folder):
    img_data_array = []
    class_name = []

    for file in os.listdir(img_folder):
        # Open the image file
        image_path = os.path.join(img_folder, file)
        image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        # Convert the image pixels to float datatype
        image = np.array(image)
        image = image.astype("float32")

        # Normalize the image to have pixel values scaled down between 0 and 1
        image /= 255

        img_data_array.append(image)
        class_name.append(file)

    return img_data_array, class_name


# extract the image array and class name
img_data, class_name = create_dataset(r"bounding_box_train")
```

The desirable array with images, ready to be used on tensorflow, will be on **img_data** variable.

Source: https://towardsdatascience.com/loading-custom-image-dataset-for-deep-learning-models-part-1-d64fa7aaeca6